# To schedule tasks and stop tasks after some time

Tags: python, schedule, zoom-sdk

Well, I am making this program which will click a link sent on zoom and close zoom at the end of meeting
This is the code

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pause
import datetime
import schedule

YEAR = 2020
MONTH = 11
DATE = 6
HOUR = 10
MINUTES = 1
SECONDS = 00
now = datetime.datetime.now()
EndTime = now.replace(hour=HOUR, minute=MINUTES, second=SECONDS, microsecond=0)
JustBefore= now.replace(hour=HOUR, minute=MINUTES-1, second=SECONDS, microsecond=0)

def leave_the_meeting():
  pyautogui.click(1198, 1072)
  time.sleep(3)
  pyautogui.click(1443, 998)
  time.sleep(1)
  pyautogui.click(1398, 933)
 
def click_the_attendance_link():
      pyautogui.click(1665, 674)
      time.sleep(9)
```

I want `click_the_attendance_link()` to keep functioning over and over again until `JustBefore` and then stop.
and then I want `leave_the_meeting()` to start functioning for just one time at `EndTime`.

What code should I add?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def keep_click_attendance_link():
  while datetime.datetime.now() < JustBefore:
    click_attendance_link()
    # Sleep for 60 secs before trying again
    time.sleep(60)

  while datetime.datetime.now() < Endtime:
    # Sleep for 1 sec intervals:
    time.sleep(1)

  # eventually Leave the meeting at Endtime
  leave_the_meeting()
```